# How to solve $f''(x)+f'(x)+ f^2(x)=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> If $$f''(x)+f'(x)+ f^2(x)=x\tag1$$ be the differential equation of a curve and let point P be the point of maxima then no. of tangents which can be drawn from point P to $x^2-y^2=a^2,a\ne0$

---

The first think that strikes me is $f'(x)=0$ for P so I would be tempted to put it as zero in original equation, but that would be wrong(my intuition says that, please explain why?).Even if we put that how to solve that?

So slope of tangent to second curve would be $2x-2yy'=0\implies y'=x/y$, or taking $x=a\sec t,y=a\tan t$, we get $y'=\csc t$. And the tangent would be $(y-a\tan t)=\csc t(x-a\sec t)=x\csc t-a\sec t\csc t\implies y=x\csc t-a\cot t$.

Then putting in equation (1) we get we should be able to find t, am I correct?

Comment: Your question doesn't parse.  First, how is $P$ defined?  Is it some point with maximum $y$ coordinate (I don't know if it makes sense to say "the" point, because we would need to prove that it is unique), or any local maximum?  And is the question to determine the number of lines passing through $P$ that are tangent to the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=a^2$?  Or do you want them to be tangent to the original curve?  Please clarify.

Comment: @Slade 1)local maxima 2)the question is to determine the number of lines passing through P that are tangent to the hyperbola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If point $(x_0, y_0) = (x_0, f(x_0))$ is a  local max of $f(x)$ you have $f'(x_0) = 0$ and $f''(x_0) \le 0$, so $y_0^2 = f(x_0)^2 = x_0 - f''(x_0) - f'(x_0) \ge x_0$, that is, the point must be on or to the left of the parabola
$x = y^2$.  Any point $(x_0, y_0)$ (strictly) to the left of that parabola will be a local max of the solution of that differential equation with initial values $f(x_0) = y_0$, $f'(x_0) = y_0$.

Now, the asymptotes to the hyperbola split the region between the two branches of the hyperbola into four regions. From any point in the interior of each region there will be
two tangents that can be drawn to the hyperbola, while from a point on one of the asymptotes only one tangent can be drawn, and from the origin (where the asymptotes intersect) no tangents can be drawn.  From a point not between the branches of the hyperbola, no tangents can be drawn.

The region to the left of the parabola thus contains points from which $0$, $1$ or $2$ tangents to the hyperbola can be drawn.